# powershell script to archive files in many subfolders

Tags: powershell

i am trying to write down a script which can help me to archive multiple files in multiple subdirs. Also i need to exclude specific files.
 So far i got that few lines script

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "D:\path\to\folder" -Exclude *i.jpeg |
  Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\excludedir($|\\)' }
foreach ($file in $files)
{
  C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -mx=9 -ms=on $file
}
```

Basically its searches recursively all subfolders for .jpeg files and  gives me the list of them excluding the ones that ends with  'i'.jpeg  lets say 'photoi.jpeg'.
This is working, but i cannot make it to the next step as i need to run 7zip for all listed files.

Can someone help me out here.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are trying save one big zip lots of individual ones, however I do something like this:

```
Set-Alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "D:\path\to\folder" -Exclude *i.jpeg |
  Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\excludedir($|\\)' }
foreach ($file in $files)
{
  $output = sz a -t7z  -mx=9 -ms=on "$File" 2>&1
}
```

You might have to modify the zipping line has I have tested it using your command line options. Another nice touch is that I have captured the output of the command for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass filenames, **not** objects, to 7z command.
*@listfile* syntax can help:

```
Get-ChildItem ...| Where-Object ...| select -expand fullname| out-file alist.txt -encoding utf8
'C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe' a archive.7z -mx=9 -ms=on `@alist.txt
Remove-item .\alist.txt
```

note the backtick before @